# Converting from week number to datetime not working: "time data '201T' does not match format '%Y' (match)"

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a dataframe series that has an output in the format of YWW, where the WW stands for work week.

I've converted this into two new columns, one for the work week and one for the year like so:

```
derp = pd.DataFrame();
derp['Releasedate'] = sndf['Releasedate'] #releasedate is a string
derp['Week'] = sndf.Releasedate.str.slice(start=4);
derp['Year'] = sndf.Releasedate.str.slice(stop=4);
derp['Year'] = '201' + derp['Year'].astype(str);
derp=derp.dropna()
```

giving me a dataframe with the following output:

__|Releasedate|Week|Year
0 | 728       | 28 |2017
1 | 742       | 42 |2017
2 | 920       | 20 |2019
3 | 813       | 13 |2008
…

However, when I try converting it to datetime with the following code

```
derp['New'] = pd.to_datetime(derp.Year.astype(str), format='%Y') + \
             pd.to_timedelta(derp.Week.mul(7).astype(str) + ' days')
```

It gives me the following error:
ValueError: time data '201T' does not match format '%Y' (match)

How do I overcome this error?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ALollz I tried using `errors = 'coerce'` like so: `derp['New'] = pd.to_datetime(derp.Year.astype(str), format='%Y', errors='coerce') + \
             pd.to_timedelta(derp.Week.mul(7).astype(str) + ' days')`. However, it gives me an overflow error "OverflowError: int too big to convert"

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion is more complicated than needed. Try this:

```
derp['New'] = pd.to_datetime(derp['Year'], format='%Y') \
                + pd.to_timedelta(derp['Week'].mul(7), unit='d')
```

Result:

```
2017-07-16
2017-10-22
2019-05-21
2008-04-01
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert the week numbers to int if you want to multiply them with 7. If you do it with them as strings you will instead get 44 seven time after one another.

This should do it

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Releasedate':['744','812']}
sndf = pd.DataFrame(data)
derp = pd.DataFrame()
derp['Releasedate'] = sndf['Releasedate'] #releasedate is a string
derp['Week'] = sndf.Releasedate.str.slice(start=1);
derp['Year'] = sndf.Releasedate.str.slice(stop=1);
derp['Year'] = '201' + derp['Year'].astype(str);
derp=derp.dropna()

derp['New'] = pd.to_datetime(derp.Year.astype(str), format='%Y') + \
             pd.to_timedelta(derp.Week.astype(int).mul(7).astype(str) + ' days')
```

Comment: So, I don't know if the date time is the problem then. when I use the sample dataset "data", everything works, even my old code. However, when I use my actual dataset, it still gives me the same error. ```sndf['Releasedate']``` is a pd series of 1000 strings, all of which are a 3 digit number like the sample data set

Comment: Would have to have a look at the sndf dataset you are using. What is your source of this, are you reading it from a file?

Comment: So I investigated the dataset, and the main problem was that some of the first digits were letters for some reason. once I filtered all of those from my dataset, everything works as normal now.